# Dynamic Calendar Link

Tags: event, custom, dynamic, calendar

I've got a functional custom public calendar going on that displays all the users events in 1 area.
I've got an outputlink displaying the entries subject line.
However I need it to open the **actual event**. I'm stuck on physically opening that event.

```
/00U/c?cType=2&md0=YEAR(TODAY())&&md3={!day.dayOfYear}
```

The above is what I currently have, which opens up the multi-user calendar view for that specific day (day view).
I am aware of what md0 - md3 etc does, but for some reason, I can't get the actual event to open. 
I have tried to find the child event ID, but no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: aren't actual events opened with `{!URLFOR($Action.Event.View,theEventId)}' ?

Answer (score 0):

`{!URLFOR($Action.Event.View,theEventId)}' was the solution